# How can I view the list of collectibles and side activites in the current location?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

When hovering over fast travel regions, the game displays for each available collectible type and side activity how many are already completed and how many are available: [image: List of collectibles and side activities for Havana]

However I cannot seem to find a way to see this overview for the current location I am im. How can I view this information for the current location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Primagames](https://primagames.com/games/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag/guides/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag-eguide/primer/default-controls-summary):
[image]

You can hold the Right Bumper on Xbox Consoles, use R2 on PS3,  R1 on PS4, and the R button on the WII U.

Not depicted on the website, but you can use your mouse's Scroll Wheel to view Collectibles on PC copies of the game.